# Кэш словарей

Tags: python, кэширование, django

В моем приложение на `Django` появилась необходимость кэшировать запросы (точнее ответы). Каким образом посоветуете это делать?

PS Поставить `pylibmc` не удалось (ошибки компиляции). Сейчас пытаюсь настроить `beaker`.

Comment: Закэшировать весь ответ, целиком? Никогда такого не видел, буду следить за ответами!

Answer (score 1):

А так?

```
from django.core.cache import cache

key = 'key'
data = cache.get(key)

if data is None:
    # update cache now...
    cache.set(data, key, 3600)
```

Comment: Это же механизм стандартного кэширования. Как Вы им предлагаете закэшировать ответ от сервера?